# Handlebars - Get value of preceding item

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js

I have the below JSON object

```
{ 
"Teams": [
    {
      "Sponsored": false,
      "Sponsor": "A",
      "TeamPosition": 1
    },
    {
      "Sponsored": true,
      "Sponsor": "D",
      "SponsorName": "SAB",
      "TeamPosition": 2
}
]
}
```

And in my template I have

```
{{#each Teams}}
     some html   
{{#each}}
```

What I want to do is while on second element of my object be able to get the value of Sponsored for the first element. As a handlebars beginner I am lost. I would want it to work in a way that I cal get the value of an element in the preceding object

I tried

```
{{#each Teams this.0.Sponsored}}
     some html   
{{#each}}
```

but it is coming back as undefined

Comment: In that context, `this` is the object containing `Teams` and anything else at the top level. Try `{{#each Teams Teams.0.Sponsored}}`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to always get the value of the first element try this:

```
{{#each Teams}}
     {{@index}} : {{Sponsored}}
     {{../Teams.[0].Sponsored}}
{{/each}}
```